# Is it better to Clear lists and refill them or simply assign an existing collection to the list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on copying/modifying a package for unity ([xNode](https://github.com/Siccity/xNode)) and I'm at the point where `NodePortDictionary` is defined.

In `OnBeforeSerialize` the original author clears both the Key and Value lists and iterates through the dictionary adding the key and value pairs to the lists.

```
public void OnBeforeSerialize() {
    keys.Clear();
    values.Clear();

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, NodePort> pair in this) {
        keys.Add(pair.Key);
        values.Add(pair.Value);
    }
}
```

Is there a reason that it should be done that way over this way?

```
public void OnBeforeSerialize() {
    keys = Keys.ToList();
    values = Values.ToList();
}
```

I'm not asking if it's 'a better practice', I'm trying to understand if its better from a performance perspective. More specifically is there enough of a difference in performance to be concerned about?

Comment: Whether a performance difference is relevant can only be answered by profiling. Generally speaking the first approach (clearing and adding) is likely to lead to fewer allocations, which in turn means less work for the garbage collector

Comment: Your title of the question and the question itself seem to be at odds. It perhaps should be "Is it better to Clear lists and refill them or simply assign a ***new*** collection to the list?"

Comment: @UnholySheep - Which will save likely save a millionth of a nanosecond for the code concerned.

Comment: The "is it better" part of the question really depends on where else the existing list may be being used. You might need to give full code for us to know that.

Comment: @Enigmativity the full code exists in the link posted, I'm just in the process of copying it into my project as well as modifying it as I go, but for the most part the code in the original repo will likely more or less remain intact (ie everywhere the dictionary will actually be used)

Comment: Though based on the response to UnholySheep's comment, it leads me to believe it likely is an irrelevant difference in performance.

Comment: @RWolfe - Differences in functionality would be the biggest concern.

Comment: There's a ***lot*** to unpack here. My *gut* feeling is that the second option is more performant in almost every single case. It's also got the advantage that it's far less code. Firstly, using a `foreach` means you're requesting an `IEnuemrator<string,NodePort>`, then iterating over that. You're then adding to a list. If the list wasn't previously 'about' the same size, then you're going to have list resizes, which essentially creates a new array and copy for every resize. This depends on your initial and new data set sizes, but I'm thinking just get the list from the collection.

Comment: Do keep in mind that calling `.ToList()` on an existing `ICollection<T>` (which a `List<T>` is) doesn't do a series of list resizes - it creates a list immediately of the required size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions are relevant only if your lists have thousands or millions of entries, of if your project is extremely time sensitive (like trying to keep under a certain time threshold, which normally happens in C or C++).

In your first code

```
public void OnBeforeSerialize() {
    keys.Clear();
    values.Clear();

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, NodePort> pair in this) {
        keys.Add(pair.Key);
        values.Add(pair.Value);
    }
}
```

Your cycle runs for the length of the list of pairs, which will have `O(n)`. In the second code

```
public void OnBeforeSerialize() {
    keys = Keys.ToList();
    values = Values.ToList();
}
```

the `.ToList()` run for the length of the list of pairs, and you have two of them, so you will run in `O(2n)`. But `O(n)=O(2n)`, so unless you have millions of entries, you won't see a big difference.

Now in terms of memory allocation, it is better to clean the variables and re-use them because of memory swap. There are concepts called **Memory Heap** and **Memory Stack**, where one is accessed faster than the other one. There are limits in how much you can keep on stack, and its not a lot. (**Homework:** check in which memory you create local variables, global variables, and where the variables can be resized and where they cannot. Also, check if `List` can be resized, or if it creates a new instance.)

About this:

1. Right now if both approaches work, it means you haven't exceeded the stack size. **Then your second approach will be faster than the first one.** The compiler will only assign a new memory address.
2. If you exceed the stack size, **your second approach won't work**. You will run into a memory exception. Your only option will be the first approach.
3. In your example, *NodePort* and *string* may not be memory aligned (which means that there is a chance the compiler does bit padding to align to *nice* lengths, i.e., 64 bits for example). So you should see what the compiler is doing behind the scenes for these variables (you will have to read the assembly code for this, which again, if your project is not time sensitive, its a waste of time).

Visual Studio has excellent profiling tools, so you can play a bit and learn about the memory allocation. Also I suggest to you to read about heap vs. stack, and you will see that there is a lot more of what meets the eye.

Check these, they might help you:

1. https://www.guru99.com/stack-vs-heap.html
2. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stack-vs-heap-memory-c-sharp/

Comment: Given the nature of what this code is designed for, there likely won't be even 10's of elements in the list, as for stack size, I'm not 100% certain, and with that uncertainty I should probably just stick with the original solution then. The project is assuredly not time-sensitive (at least if we exclude simply wanting it to 'run' fast so we can work faster).

Comment: @RWolfe These kind of questions teach you A LOT of C, C++ and C#. It is natural to ask "Why they did it like *this* and not like *this*?". A lot of times its because scalability, i.e., when your code has millions of bits of data, one approach is better than the other. I suggest to you read the *homework* and links I added to my answer, they might help you in the future. And good job asking this question!